# Displaying information over video

Tags: iphone, ios, video, dynamic

I am building an app for iOS (iPhone and iPad) where the user is able to watch video clips of therapeutic exercises. However, I want to overlay some dynamically generated information (the amount of reps and sets assigned to them by their physio)  either "over" or next to the video playing. The amount of reps and sets will be like a counter counting down the amount of work they have left before the next exercise will start playing.

Here is a mock-up of what I would like to achieve if possible [Video with dynamic information overlay](http://imm.io/J7LH)

So while the video is playing the "Hold" will count for a specified number of seconds. When the time limit is reached, "Sets" is increased by 1 and Hold starts from 0 again. When the Sets are all completed, "Reps" increase by 1 and Hold and Reps start back at 0. Etc.

Can the video playing and all this information be displayed simultaneously on the iPhone/iPad?

I have looked at a number of video hosting solutions that might have this feature built into it, but couldnt find anything that would suit my needs.

Is this possible at all as I have never seen anything like this done before?

Could a solution be to use a iFrame to display the video and then have all the other information that I want on the screen separate to this? Just a thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, have a look at this example project:

http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273

This is for a camera overlay, but it also works for existing videos.